# Derivative of a multimode squeezed vacuum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics, squeezed-states

Let us suppose we have a multimode squeezed vacuum state of the form
\begin{equation}
|\psi\rangle =  \exp[A]|0\rangle= \exp \big[\sum_{ij}G_{ij}(t) (a_i a_j -a_i^\dagger a_j^\dagger)\big]
|0\rangle\end{equation}
where $[a_i,a_j^\dagger]=\delta_{ij}$ are the annihilation/creation operators, $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum state $a_i|0\rangle=0$ and $G_{ij}(t)$ is a real symmetric matrix which depends on a parameter $t$.

Is there some way to calculate the derivative of this state, or at least approximate its norm $\langle \partial_t \psi|\partial_t \psi\rangle$? Because of $[\partial_t A, A]\neq 0$, $|\partial_t \psi \rangle = \exp[A] \partial_t A |0\rangle$ is generally not true. If it were true, we would have $\langle \partial_t \psi|\partial_t \psi\rangle \approx\langle 0| \partial_t A^\dagger \partial_t A |0\rangle$, which can be easily calculated.

The derivative can be approximated if the $G_{ij}$ are small. Then, only the first two terms of the exponential series are relevant, that is $\exp[A]|0\rangle \approx |0\rangle + A|0\rangle$, and we have approximately $\langle \partial_t \psi|\partial_t \psi\rangle \approx \langle 0| \partial_t A^\dagger \partial_t A |0\rangle$. Is it generally true that $\langle \partial_t \psi|\partial_t \psi\rangle \approx \langle 0| \partial_t A^\dagger \partial_t A |0\rangle$ ? Or is there some lower bound of the norm that can be easily calculated and is potentially related to $\langle 0| \partial_t A^\dagger \partial_t A |0\rangle$?

Comment: Try Eq. 1.11 and 2.3 of this paper: https://www.osapublishing.org/josab/abstract.cfm?uri=josab-10-8-1347

Comment: I think you are thinking about bringing the state into the form of Eq. (94) in http://www.paper.edu.cn/scholar/showpdf/NUz2cNwINTD0AxeQh

Comment: However, now the normalization constant depends on the parameter and I don't see how to derive a lower bound for derivative

Comment: You might find something in https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540678021. Are the $G_{ij}(t)$ sympletic matrices?

Comment: Because then you might rewrite $G_{ij}(a_ia_j-a_i^{\dagger}a_j^{\dagger})$ as $U(t)(a_ia_j-a_i^{\dagger}a_j^{\dagger})U^{\dagger}(t)$ and the exponential finally as $U(t)\exp[\sum_{ij}a_ia_j-a_i^{\dagger}a_j^{\dagger}]U^{\dagger}(t)$, so the derivative calculations may get easier.